# What is the use of img tag in analytics implementations

Tags: web, analytics

```
<noscript><img src="http://daydocumentation.112.2o7.net/b/ss/daydocumentation/1/H.25--NS/1380120772954?cdp=3&amp;gn=content%3Ageometrixx-outdoors%3Aen" height="1" width="1" border="0" alt=""/></noscript>
```

Please help me understand what it does, why do we use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, nowadays most analytics tools use JavaScript because it allows to gather much more statistical data about the user entering the website. However, some browsers either don't support JavaScript (rare), or have JavaScript support turned off for security reasons. For these browsers, the custom-generated image (usually 1px by 1px) is used - its only use is to capture the data about the browser of the user that requests this image. The various components of the URL are probably an encoded way of providing the details of the specific analytics location to the analytics server.

Comment: Thanks Piotr. Can you please comment on what is the significance of "1/H.25--NS/1380120772954" part in above URL. Also as you said If the purpose of including this URL is to just send some information to server through parameters, then H code version the other information in URL, are they really needed?

Comment: Yes, it's probably an encoded piece of information about the specific analytics (like, say, type of statistics or exact identifier of the customer). The details are probably only known to the analytics provider, but I would not remove anything from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

That is not part of Google Analytics. The 2o7.net Domain belongs to Adobe, and the "geometrixx" part of the image source suggests that this is part of the material Adobe provides in their software training (they use the fictitious geometrixx shop as example). H.25 is a version number for Adobe Analytics tracking code.

If this is included in a live site this is most likely by accident. Else I'd guess, since this is wrapped in noscript tags, that this is supposed to be a fallback tracking pixel for browser that do not have  javascript enabled (although I doubt that this is properly configured).